# DIfferent Objects in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, list, android-recyclerview

Good morning,
I need to make a list with different classes of object and list them in this single recycler view. Such as: Recycler products and i need to list potatos, bananas and milk. Obviously they are different objects.

I don't know how to do that, because of the method onBindViewHolder. I need to get the item from list and create an object so i can recover data, but I don't know if it is milk, banana or potato.

My idea is: Create product class with Type String Atribute, so I recover the item from list, create an object product, get type value and if is equals to "banana", I create a banana object and recover data values. Is this a good option?

Comment: You should look into Polymorphism.

Comment: i suggest you should create one model class(object class) for example lets say MainObject.class. now you need to create objects of your other class , lets take Banana Class , so need to add Banana banana=new Banana() in MainObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an interface `Product` where each class `Potato`, `Banana` and `Milk` will implement this interface, so your adapter will contain a list of `Products`.

If all items will be represented the same way (e.g name + image) - add those properties to the interface and every thing will be easy.

If you need to handle each class differently (e.g you need a specific property that only class `Milk` has) you can check which class is your current product on `onBindViewHolder` method like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Product currentProduct = productLst.get(position);
    if (currentProduct instanceof Banana) {
        // this is a banana
    } else if (currentProduct instanceof Milk){
        // this is milk
    } else if (currentProduct instanceof Potato){
        // this is Potato
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, this solves the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way

1. create a super class say BaseObjectClass
2. Then extend all of your class with created BaseObject class (Class A extends BaseObjectClass\ in kotlin class A:BaseObjectClass())
3. Now when you create list for recyclerview creat list of BaseObject type (List)
4. in onBindViewHolder check type of object with method ((item) instanceof (A)) and so on..

```
abstract class BaseObject {
}

class A extends  BaseObject{

}

class B extends BaseObject{

}

class C extends BaseObject{

}


class TestRecyclerViewAdatper extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{
............................................
    List<BaseObject> list = new ArrayList<BaseObject>();
................................................
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        BaseObject item = list.get(position);
        if(item instanceof A){
            A a = (A) item;
        }else if(item instanceof B){
            B b = (B) item;

        }
    }

.........................................................
...........................
}
```